# How long does the F9 first stage remain hypersonic under control of its grid fins?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, reuse

How long is the first stage of a landing Falcon 9 remain hypersonic, and under control of its grid fins? Specifically the hypersonic component is of interest.

(Future second question will be, based on 6 attempts so far with grid fins, has SpaceX exceeded the record for controlled hypersonic flight yet?)

Answer (score 6):

Addressing the "has SpaceX exceeded the record" part of the question:

This [graph](http://www.spaceacademy.net.au/spacelink/blackout.htm) shows that a Space Shuttle reentry was in the hypersonic flight regime for approximately 25 minutes.  (I took 1.7 km/s ~ Mach 5 ~ end of hypersonic regime).

[image]

I'm pretty sure that's longer than the entire flight time for a recovered Falcon 9 first stage.

Answer (score 0):

The F9 first stage remains hypersonic until only shortly before landing - this is evidenced by the sonic boom emitted shortly before landing as it transitions to subsonic speed probably less than 10 seconds before landing.

Comment: This may or may not be true (I don't know), but keep in mind that there is something in between *subsonic* and *hypersonic*, namely *non-hypersonic supersonic*. Borrowing from Wikipedia: *In aerodynamics, a hypersonic speed is one that is highly supersonic. Since the 1970s, the term has generally been assumed to refer to speeds of Mach 5 and above.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersonic_speed